# Concatenating elements of unpacked array together

Tags: system-verilog

I am using the following function in my System Verilog code. I wondered if there was an idiomatic way of achieving the same effect that perhaps would not require the width to be hardwired. I tried streaming operators, but could not quite get them to work. I need to use unpacked arrays. Many thanks.

```
function bit [64:0] cat8 (bit [7:0] a[8]);
   return { a[7], a[6], a[5], a[4], a[3], a[2], a[1], a[0] };
endfunction;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you reversing the array in concat, there is no good way to express it.
you have:

```
bit [7:0] a[8];
```

which is equivalent to

```
bit [7:0] a[0:7];
```

in your concat you start with `a[7]` in the most significant bits whether `7` is the least significant index in the array.

This is the reason why the streaming operators did not work in your case.

So, if you really need to reverse the array, than you have what you have, otherwise you can find that these 2 things are equivalent:

```
{ a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7] }
```

and

```
{ >> {a}}
```

of course you can declare your array as `bit [7:0] a[7:0]` and keep index ordering in concat as you have. But it will **not** reverse the array again, as in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a new datatype through `typedef`.

```
typedef bit[7:0] octet;
typedef octet upack[7:0];

function bit [64:0] cat8 (upack a);
  // your code
endfunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work for you

```
module top;
  function bit [63:0] cat8 (bit [7:0] a[8]);
   return { <<8{a}};
    endfunction;
    bit [7:0] arr[8];

    initial begin
    arr= '{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    foreach (arr[i])$display("%h", arr[i]);
        $display("%h", cat8(arr));
    end
endmodule
```